# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, openssl 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.16 and CVE-2014-0224

Tags: 12.04, ssl, openssl

I've installed `openssl 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.16` on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and restarted nginx. I still receive the warning from https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest

```
Experimental: This server is vulnerable to the OpenSSL CCS vulnerability 
(CVE-2014-0224) and exploitable. Grade set to F.
```

Any way to fix?

Answer (score 0):

This is a mistake (note that this test is marked as "Experimental", so is probably still not reliable). CVE-2014-0224 was [fixed](http://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2014/CVE-2014-0224.html) in Ubuntu 12.04 in [openssl 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.14](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/openssl/1.0.1-4ubuntu5.14).